# How to get python to read and type things in windows CMD

Tags: python, windows, cmd, virtual-machine

I am writing a program that needs to know whether or not it's in a virtual machine, a neat way I found was to check the system information in the cmd, however, I can't find a way to write in the cmd and read what the cmd replies.

I would like something that can write "WMIC COMPUTERSYSTEM GET MANUFACTURER" to the cmd and also check what the results are.

Comment: Programmers don't call user commands. If a user can do it a program has a programming way of doing it. See http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/tutorial.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the subprocess module

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen(
    [
        'WMIC',
        'COMPUTERSYSTEM',
        'GET',
        'MANUFACTURER'
    ],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE
)

out, err = proc.communicate()
print(out.decode().strip())
```

Comment: Running wmic.exe doesn't need `shell=True`.

Comment: I think @eryksun is right. Take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3172470) for more information...

Comment: I don't think it hurts to add it, but I removed it for simplicity.